# How can i reduce my sqlite3 code using variables?

Tags: python, sqlite

I got around 500 lines of sqlite code and i am trying to reduce that number. So i tried making a function with variables.

I tried using this code:

```
x = "c.execute("
o = "'"
y = "'INSERT INTO "
unio = x+y
tabl = ["d","d_2","n_d","n_d_2"]
val = "VALUES ("
w = ") "
k = "?,?"
mark = 369
ek = 963
def db_up(table,):
    aa = y+table+"("+tabl[0] + ", " + tabl[1]+w+val+k+")"+"',"+"(mark,ek,)"
    bb = unio+table+"("+tabl[1]+ ", " + tabl[1]+w+val+k+")"+"',"+"(mark,ek,))"
    print(aa)  # 'INSERT INTO avg_dt(d, d_2) VALUES (?,?)',(mark,ek,)
    print(bb)  # c.execute('INSERT INTO avg_dt(d_2, d_2) VALUES (?,?)',(mark,ek,))
    c.execute(str(aa))  # no succes
    c.execute(aa)  # no success
    bb  # no success
```

When i run the "c.execute(aa)" line. it throws me this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'INSERT INTO avg_dt(d, d_2) VALUES (?,?)'": syntax error
```

So...how can i make a sqlite3 code using variables a functions?
Thanks for taking the time ;)

Comment: We have no idea what any of those variables are and what goal your function is trying to accomplish

Comment: use variables which means something. Variable `x` means nothing. And maybe better create query without vairables to make it more readable and to reduce code. Query with all your variables is unreadable.

Comment: BTW: you can't use string `"query, args"` in `execute()`. They have to be separated items in `execute("query", args)`

Comment: i put the in the # the print results for "aa, bb"

Comment: `aa` is a string `"query, args" `but `execute()` needs string only with `"query"` and `args` has to be tuple - `execute("string_query", tuple_args)`

Comment: instead of all of variables create one query and use string formating - like `"INSERT INTO {}({},{}) VALUES (?,?)".format(table, tabl[0], tabl[1])`

Answer (score 2):

I can't post a comment with my current rep, so let me try to provide a full answer.

Your approach seems to be that you have too much SQL code, which you consider a problem, so you're trying to "compress" the code by reducing common statements into shorter variable names. There are a number of reasons you should avoid doing this, and a number of better ways to achieve a similar result.

First, let's talk about why this is a bad idea:

- **Your code doesn't become more maintainable.** Interspersing cryptic variable names like `x`, `o`, `y`, or `unio` doesn't make the code *any* easier to read, even for the author, assuming a few days have passed since you wrote it.
- **Using this kind of method doesn't make your code any more performant**, and most likely makes it *less* performant: your program now has to worry about allocating and reallocating memory when doing string interpolation or concatenation, which takes cycles.
- **Doing string interpolation or concatenation in SQL should be done with extreme caution:** this is essentially a homebrew version of [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), which are usually authored by people with loads of experience doing SQL programming. Making this on your own risks your program being targetted by SQL injection (or at least column/value type mismatches).

Now, let's talk about mitigating this issue for you:

- **Lots of SQL code need not be unmanageable:** typically, if you *must* maintain large amounts of raw SQL in your project, you dump that into a separate SQL file which you can then either execute directly from the database CLI or run from your program via a database driver.
- **ORMs are** (usually) **your friend:** with the exception of exotic or *outstandingly performance-sensitive* SQL queries, modern ORMs can get rid of most raw SQL code in your program. The more naturally programmatic structure of ORM code also means you can break it up into different delegate functions to avoid code reuse, to an extent.

Please feel free to add details to your question; as it stands, it's not totally clear whether your concerns can be addressed with this answer.